# Solving $ 2^{2010}\frac{\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x)^{1004}dx}{\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x^{2010})^{1004}dx}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$ 2^{2010}\frac{\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x)^{1004}dx}{\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x^{2010})^{1004}dx}$$

Try: Let $\displaystyle I =\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x)^{1004}dx$ and $\displaystyle J =\int^{1}_{0}x^{1004}(1-x^{2010})^{1004}dx$

put $x^{1005}=t$ and $\displaystyle x^{1004}dx=\frac{1}{1005}dt$

So $\displaystyle J =\frac{1}{1005}\int^{1}_{0}(1-t^2)dt$

Now i am struck here , I did not understand how to solve it

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: Bhai beta function ki property check kar le wikipedia se. Best of luck.

Comment: bhai tu sahi bola ye beta baba hee hain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitution $x^{1005} = t$, we have
$$J = \frac{1}{1005}\int_0^1 (1 - t^2)^{1004} \mathrm{d} t. \tag{1}$$

With the substitution $t = 1 - 2u$, we have
$$J = \frac{1}{1005}\int_0^{1/2} 2^{2009}u^{1004}(1 - u)^{1004}\mathrm{d} u . \tag{2}$$

With the substitution $u = 1 - v$, we have
$$J = \frac{1}{1005}\int_{1/2}^1 2^{2009}v^{1004}(1 - v)^{1004}\mathrm{d} v. \tag{3}$$

Using (2) and (3), we have
$$J = \frac12\cdot \frac{1}{1005}
\int_0^1 2^{2009}u^{1004}(1 - u)^{1004}\mathrm{d} u
= \frac{1}{4020}2^{2010}I.$$

Thus,
$$2^{2010}I/J = 4020.$$

Comment: I really appreciate your method, without using any non-elementary functions. Well worked, thanks a ton!!! :D

Comment: @user983206 You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With $a = 1004$ and $b = 2010$ and $B$ the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$\eqalign{I &= {\frac {a{\rm B} \left(a,a\right)}{4\,a+2}}\cr
J &= \frac{a{\rm B} \left(a,\frac{a+1}{b}\right)}{ab + a + 1}
 }
$$
and thus $$\frac{I}{J} = \frac{1+a+ab}{4a+2} \frac{{\rm B}(a,a)}{{\rm B}(a,(a+1)/b)}$$
In your case I get
$$ 2^{2010} I/J = 4020$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the advantage of the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

$$ x^a\,(1-x^b)^c=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{c}{n} x^{a+b n}$$
$$\int x^a\,(1-x^b)^c\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{c}{n}\frac{x^{a+b n+1}}{a+b n+1}=x^{a+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{c}{n}\frac{x^{b n}}{a+b n+1}$$
$$\int x^a\,(1-x^b)^c\,dx=\frac {x^{a+1}}{a+1}\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{b},-c;\frac{a+b+1}{b};x^b\right)$$
$$\int_0^1 x^a\,(1-x^b)^c\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (c+1) \,\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{b}\right)}{b \,\Gamma \left(\frac{a+b+bc+1}{b}\right)}$$ provided that $\Re(b)>0\land \Re(c)>-1\land \Re(a)>-1$.

If $a=c$ as in your question
$$\int_0^1 x^a\,(1-x^b)^a\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (a+1) \,\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{b}\right)}{b\,\Gamma \left(\frac{(a+1)\, (b+1)}{b}\right)}$$ which can reduce also to beta function.